# Two Pandas + Map + Group by (two variables) + count

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I have two data frames: clients & messages

For each client there are several messages. Both have dates (from which I extract the day). That means for the client is the day they sign up; for the messages the day when the message is sent.

I can know the total messages sent for each client just with:

```
clients['total'] = clients['ID'].map(messages.groupby(['ID']).counts())
```

But: how can I extend that to **count how many messages where sent the day they sign up**, instead that in the whole period? I try to group by two variables

```
clients['totalDay1'] = clients['ID'].map(messages.groupby(['ID','Day']).counts())
```

But I don't get where I want, that is to add the value to the client df.

Thank you!
Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need `join`:

```
s = messages.groupby(['ID','Day']).size().rename('totalDay1')
clients = clients.join(s, on=['ID','Day'])
```

Sample:

```
messages = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 'Day':[1,2,2], 'col':[3,4,5]})
clients = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,5], 'Day':[1,2,2], 'col':[4,5,6]})

s = messages.groupby(['ID','Day']).size().rename('totalDay1')
clients = clients.join(s,  on=['ID','Day'])
print (clients)
   ID  Day  col  totalDay1
0   1    1    4        1.0
1   2    2    5        1.0
2   5    2    6        NaN
```